# Is there a quick way to open a file anywhere within a directory hierarchy?

Tags: filesystem

I am working with a <s>new</s> old code base where virtually all the interesting source files are three levels deep in the directory hierarchy. It's about 1.3M lines of code in more than 2000 `.cpp` files. The project `Makefile` is set up so that when a compiler error happens, only the file *name* part of the file in question is shown, rather than the *path* to that file.

What I'd like to do is be able to ask vim to open a file by name only, and have it look through the directory tree to find that name for me.

I already have a `tags` file set up so I can jump to identifiers without caring which directory or source file name they're in, but that doesn't help for actual file names themselves.

Is there a native vim way, or a plugin, that can help with this? My ideal solution would be something that would modify the `:n` command so that:

- If a path is provided (even just `./`), the behaviour is unchanged;
- If only a file name is provided, and a file by that name doesn't exist in the current directory, vim would search through the whole tree under the current directory looking for a file by that name. If one is found, open that.

A solution that uses a different command than `:n` would be fine.

Comment: this should be more ore less easy with vimscript (look at `findfile()` http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#findfile%28%29). If it really needs to overwrite the `:n` command this may help: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev. However I would use something like this https://github.com/junegunn/fzf it is not exactly the solution to your `:n` command, but in my experience this changes (improves) your whole vim workflow and you don't need that stuff. But my experience is quite limited, so maybe have a look at it, but don't let me dictate your workflow =)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: Thanks, your hint led me to an easy built-in solution!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by setting the [`'path'` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27path%27) to include `**`, and then using the `:find` command:

```
:set path=.,,**
:find filename.cpp
```

The section on [File Searching](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#file-searching) in the documentation describes how the `**` path wildcard works.

Answer (score 1):

[CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) should help you. Once you set it up, it is as simple as pressing Ctrl + P (or you can have custom mapping) and typing(or pasting) the name of file.